# getView in Android ViewHolder sometimes returning `null`

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

The show more text displays intermittently on some list items in a RecyclerView. if the `description` text extends passed 5 lines, show more should be displayed. This doesn't appear to be an issue with a single item.

[image]

The `description` is a TextView found inside the ViewHolder. After doing some debugging I found that `description.layout` (getLayout) is sometimes returning `null`, so it can't action the rest of the logic.

I tried to find why the `layout` is sometimes returning null, so added a `addOnLayoutChangeListener` to find if the sizes where changing, it turned out whenever it is `null`, the `addOnLayoutChangeListener` returns some new values for `bottom` and `right`

Below is the snipper from my Task's ViewHolder, where the logic to show / hide `show more` `show less` text.

```
    Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).post {
        description.layout?.let { l ->
            val lines = l.lineCount
            if (expanded || lines > 0 && l.getEllipsisCount(lines - 1) > 0) {
                showMoreLess.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                showMoreLess.setOnClickListener { showMoreLessTapped() }
            } else {
                showMoreLess.visibility = View.GONE
                showMoreLess.setOnClickListener {  }
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
/**
 * Adapter for job details view.
 *
 * @param navigator a class responsible for navigation
 * @param context the context
 * @param locationManager manages location services
 * @param transitionToWorkflowStep a lambda that handles triggering a workflow transition as well as any UI specific
 * @param customFieldClickListener a lambda that handles triggering an input dialog for each customfield type
 * @param notesClickListener a lambda that handles notes field click
 * @param jobActionCompletionClickListener a lambda that handles secondary action completion note click
 * actions that need to happen.
 */
class JobDetailsAdapter(
    private val navigator: Navigator,
    val context: Context,
    private val locationManager: LocationManager,
    private val transitionToWorkflowStep: (JobDetailsItemModel.JobDetailsAction) -> Unit,
    private val customFieldClickListener: (customField: CustomFieldItem) -> Unit,
    private val notesClickListener: () -> Unit,
    private val jobActionCompletionClickListener: () -> Unit,
    private val taskClickListener: (task: JobDetailsItemModel.TaskItem, checked: Boolean) -> Unit,
    private val showReadOnlyAlert: () -> Unit,
    private val showNavigationOptions:
        (action: JobDetailsItemModel.JobDetailsAction, fromStartTravelWorkflow: Boolean) -> Unit
) : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

    init {
        setHasStableIds(true)
    }

    private val items: MutableList<JobDetailsItemModel> = mutableListOf()
    private var readOnly: Boolean = false

    companion object {
        private val ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_TITLE = R.layout.list_item_job_details_header_title
        private val ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_WARNING = R.layout.list_item_job_details_header_warning
        private val ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_ALERT = R.layout.list_item_job_details_header_alert
        private val ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_INFO = R.layout.list_item_job_details_header_information
        private val ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_ACTIONS = R.layout.list_item_job_details_header_actions
        private val ITEM_TYPE_RESOURCES = R.layout.list_item_job_details_resources
        private val ITEM_TYPE_LIST_ITEM_CELL = R.layout.component_list_item_cell
        private val ITEM_TYPE_CUSTOM_FIELD = R.layout.component_custom_field_cell
        private val ITEM_TYPE_LIST_ITEM_TITLE_HEADER = R.layout.list_item_title_header
        private val ITEM_TYPE_TASK = R.layout.list_item_task
        private val ITEM_TYPE_STATUS = R.layout.list_item_job_details_job_status
        private val ITEM_TYPE_TIME_ON_JOB = R.layout.list_item_job_details_time_on_job
        private val ITEM_TYPE_MAP = R.layout.list_item_job_details_map
        private val ITEM_TYPE_ACCOUNT = R.layout.list_item_job_details_account
        private val ITEM_TYPE_CONTACT = R.layout.list_item_job_details_contact
    }

    private val resourceTapped = { jobId: UID<SchemaType.Job> ->
        navigator.navigateToResources(context as Activity, jobId)
    }

    private val jobEditorActionTapped = { jobId: UID<SchemaType.Job>, jobEditor: JobEditorAction ->
        when (jobEditor) {
            JobEditorAction.JobNotes -> {
                notesClickListener()
            }
        }
    }

    private val jobActionsTapped =
        { tertiaryActions: List<WorkflowTertiaryActionItem>?,
          jobAction: JobDetailsItemModel.JobDetailsAction? ->
            val activity = context as Activity
            val dialogView: LinearLayout =
                activity.layoutInflater.inflate(
                    R.layout.bottom_sheet_job_actions,
                    null
                ) as LinearLayout
            val dialog = BottomSheetDialog(activity)
            tertiaryActions?.forEach { tertiaryAction ->
                val actionItem =
                    activity.layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.bottom_sheet_job_actions_item, null)
                val locale = context.resources.configuration.locales.get(0)
                when (tertiaryAction.action) {
                    WorkflowManualAction.CancelJob -> {
                        actionItem.action_item_button.text =
                            tertiaryAction.title.forLanguage(locale)
                        actionItem.action_item_button.setOnClickListener {
                            navigator.toCancelJob(activity, tertiaryAction.extras!! as String)
                        }
                    }
                    WorkflowManualAction.ManageJobTimes -> {
                        actionItem.action_item_button.text =
                            tertiaryAction.title.forLanguage(locale)
                        actionItem.action_item_button.setOnClickListener {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Edit Job Times clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        }
                    }
                    WorkflowManualAction.CompletionNote -> {
                        actionItem.action_item_button.text =
                            tertiaryAction.title.forLanguage(locale)
                        actionItem.action_item_button.setOnClickListener {
                            jobActionCompletionClickListener()
                            dialog.dismiss()
                        }
                    }
                    WorkflowManualAction.FollowUpJob -> {
                        actionItem.action_item_button.text =
                            tertiaryAction.title.forLanguage(locale)
                        actionItem.action_item_button.setOnClickListener {
                            Toast.makeText(activity, "Follow Up Job clicked", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                                .show()
                        }
                    }
                    WorkflowManualAction.Navigate -> {
                        actionItem.action_item_button.text =
                            tertiaryAction.title.forLanguage(locale)
                        actionItem.action_item_button.setOnClickListener {
                            jobAction?.let {
                                showNavigationOptions(it, false)
                                dialog.dismiss()
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                dialogView.addView(actionItem)
            }

            dialog.setContentView(dialogView)
            dialog.show()
        }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return items[position].itemId
    }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int) =
        when (viewType) {
            ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_TITLE -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_TITLE, parent, false)
                HeaderTitleViewHolder(view)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_WARNING -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_WARNING, parent, false)
                HeaderWarningViewHolder(view)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_ALERT -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_ALERT, parent, false)
                HeaderAlertViewHolder(view)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_INFO -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_INFO, parent, false)
                JobInfoViewHolder(view)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_ACTIONS -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_ACTIONS, parent, false)
                JobActionsViewHolder(view, context)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_RESOURCES -> {
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(ITEM_TYPE_RESOURCES, parent, false)
                JobResourcesViewHolder(view, resourceTapped)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_LIST_ITEM_CELL -> {
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(ITEM_TYPE_LIST_ITEM_CELL, parent, false)
                ListItemCellViewHolder(view, jobEditorActionTapped)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_CUSTOM_FIELD -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(ITEM_TYPE_CUSTOM_FIELD, parent, false)
                CustomFieldViewHolder(view, customFieldClickListener)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_LIST_ITEM_TITLE_HEADER -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                    .inflate(ITEM_TYPE_LIST_ITEM_TITLE_HEADER, parent, false)
                ListItemHeaderTitleViewHolder(view)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_TASK -> {
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(ITEM_TYPE_TASK, parent, false)
                TaskViewHolder(view)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_STATUS -> {
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(ITEM_TYPE_STATUS, parent, false)
                JobStatusViewHolder(view)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_TIME_ON_JOB -> {
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                        .inflate(ITEM_TYPE_TIME_ON_JOB, parent, false)
                TimeOnJobViewHolder(view)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_MAP -> {
                val view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(ITEM_TYPE_MAP, parent, false)
                JobDetailsMapViewHolder(view)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_ACCOUNT -> {
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(ITEM_TYPE_ACCOUNT, parent, false)
                JobDetailsAccountViewHolder(view)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_CONTACT -> {
                val view =
                    LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(ITEM_TYPE_CONTACT, parent, false)
                JobDetailsContactViewHolder(view)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) =
        when (holder.itemViewType) {
            ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_TITLE -> {
                (holder as HeaderTitleViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderTitleItem)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_WARNING -> {
                (holder as HeaderWarningViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderWarningItem)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_ALERT -> {
                (holder as HeaderAlertViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderAlertItem)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_INFO -> {
                (holder as JobInfoViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderJobInfoItem)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_ACTIONS -> {
                val jobActionsViewHolder = holder as JobActionsViewHolder
                val model = items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderActionsItem
                model.transitionToWorkflowStep = transitionToWorkflowStep
                model.onJobActionsTapped = jobActionsTapped
                jobActionsViewHolder.bind(model)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_RESOURCES -> {
                (holder as JobResourcesViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.JobResourcesItem)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_LIST_ITEM_CELL -> {
                (holder as ListItemCellViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.ListCellItem)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_CUSTOM_FIELD -> {
                (holder as CustomFieldViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.CustomFieldItem)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_LIST_ITEM_TITLE_HEADER -> {
                (holder as ListItemHeaderTitleViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderTitleListItem)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_TASK -> {
                (holder as TaskViewHolder).bind(
                    items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.TaskItem,
                    context,
                    taskClickListener,
                    readOnly,
                    showReadOnlyAlert
                )
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_STATUS -> {
                (holder as JobStatusViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.JobStatusItem)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_TIME_ON_JOB -> {
                (holder as TimeOnJobViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.TimeOnJobItem)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_MAP -> {
                (holder as JobDetailsMapViewHolder).bind(
                    items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.MapItem,
                    context,
                    locationManager
                )
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_ACCOUNT -> {
                (holder as JobDetailsAccountViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.AccountItem)
            }
            ITEM_TYPE_CONTACT -> {
                (holder as JobDetailsContactViewHolder)
                    .bind(items[position] as JobDetailsItemModel.ContactItem)
            }
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(
        holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder,
        position: Int,
        payloads: MutableList<Any>
    ) {
        onBindViewHolder(holder, position)
    }

    override fun onViewRecycled(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        super.onViewRecycled(holder)
        if (holder is JobDetailsMapViewHolder) {
            holder.clearView()
        }
    }

    override fun onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder) {
        holder.itemView.clearAnimation()
        super.onViewDetachedFromWindow(holder)
    }

    override fun getItemCount(): Int = items.size

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int =
        when (items[position]) {
            is JobDetailsItemModel.CustomFieldItem -> ITEM_TYPE_CUSTOM_FIELD
            is JobDetailsItemModel.ListCellItem -> ITEM_TYPE_LIST_ITEM_CELL
            is JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderTitleItem -> ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_TITLE
            is JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderWarningItem -> ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_WARNING
            is JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderAlertItem -> ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_ALERT
            is JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderTitleListItem -> ITEM_TYPE_LIST_ITEM_TITLE_HEADER
            is JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderJobInfoItem -> ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_INFO
            is JobDetailsItemModel.JobResourcesItem -> ITEM_TYPE_RESOURCES
            is JobDetailsItemModel.HeaderActionsItem -> ITEM_TYPE_HEADER_ACTIONS
            is JobDetailsItemModel.TaskItem -> ITEM_TYPE_TASK
            is JobDetailsItemModel.JobStatusItem -> ITEM_TYPE_STATUS
            is JobDetailsItemModel.TimeOnJobItem -> ITEM_TYPE_TIME_ON_JOB
            is JobDetailsItemModel.MapItem -> ITEM_TYPE_MAP
            is JobDetailsItemModel.AccountItem -> ITEM_TYPE_ACCOUNT
            is JobDetailsItemModel.ContactItem -> ITEM_TYPE_CONTACT
            else -> throw IllegalArgumentException()
        }

    fun addItems(jobItems: List<JobDetailsItemModel>) {
        items.clear()
        items.addAll(jobItems)
        notifyDataSetChanged()
    }

    fun updateCurrentWorkflowStep(workflowStep: WorkflowStep) {
        readOnly = workflowStep.readOnlyForResources
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to see the new values for bottom and right? When something goes completely invisible (GONE) it gets forced to the top left, meaning bottom and right become  0 and 0.

Comment: post adapters code at first

Comment: When it hits addOnLayoutChangeListener, it does return values for bottom and right. However, it only intermittently hits the addOnLayoutChangeListener.

Comment: @Nims Are you sure that you are getting uniqueId for override 'fun getItemId(position: Int): Long' ? Check if this is happening if you are not using stableIds.

Comment: Hi @HarisDautović yep, they both definitely have unique ID's. I just double checked this to be sure :) Thanks.

Comment: I've been looking at at the kotlin extendion .doOnLayout https://cheesecakelabs.com/blog/understanding-android-views-dimensions-set/ -> It doesn't appear to fire when the recycler view page is first opened, but if you scroll out of view and back the tasks it works.